# C# dynamically removing text in a string and replacing it with a image from azure

Tags: c#, sql, image, azure

Good day

How would I go about removing a section of a string with a image for example.

string Description = "Good day my name is Joe Bloggs and my favorite instrument is [[485]]";

The number in the text is linked to a image in SQL database as a reference. The image that contains the same reference number will then need to replace the [[485]] with the image.

Comment: just use string.replace()!

Comment: How you want to replace a substring with an image?

Comment: How do you want to display the image?

Comment: In what?  A web page? Do you want to show the image or a link to the image?  Please show the expected output in your question.  A screenshot of the text being displayed without the image may help.

Comment: @TimSchmelter :oh! I think he want to replace with image address!

Comment: @JeffUK I want to show the image. I have an example, i tried pasting the image of how i'd like it to work into this comment box but it won't work.

Comment: Ok then, please post the relevant code that currently displays the text to the user.

Comment: @TimSchmelter not the image address but the actual photo. So i would have "Good day my name is Joe Bloggs" and then the image next to it. Keeping in mind there will be multiple images so it needs to pull in a specific image. Hence i decided to use a reference number

Comment: How do you want to show it?  Printed out? On a web page inside img tags? On a HTML5 Canvas? Inside a windows forms application? As a sprite in a game? beamed directly to the users' brain? 3D Printed on the head of a pin?

Answer (score 3):

Generally you need following steps

1.parse the string and extracrt 485 as ID of an image

2.retrieve an image by ID and place it somewhere end users can access it.

3.craft an ouptput (HTML markup or something) refering the text and the image retrieved.

Which step causes the problem?